# Using bittrex api to get uuid not working

Tags: php, bots, uuid

```
function bittrexbuy($apikey, $apisecret, $symbol, $quant, $rate){
    $nonce=time();
    $uri='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/buylimit?apikey='.$apikey.'&market=BTC-'.$symbol.'&quantity='.$quant.'&rate='.$rate.'&nonce='.$nonce;
    $sign=hash_hmac('sha512',$uri,$apisecret);
    $ch = curl_init($uri);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
    $execResult = curl_exec($ch);
    $obj = json_decode($execResult, true);
    $uuid = $obj["result"]["uuid"];
    return $uuid;
}
```

so this is my code for getting a buylimit through. When I don't echo anything the page shows up with the result which I can't interact with. It shows up

```
{"success":false,"message":"MIN_TRADE_REQUIREMENT_NOT_MET","result":null}
```

which I'm supposed to get with my $obj and get the uuid from there but it just echo itself. Also with $uuid I don't seem to get the uuid, when I echo the $obj which it shouldn't work, it shows up with "1". Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I read that it may be a policy recently applied by Bittrex, when a selllimit is made from a bot, you can be sure that it is not the limit allowed or the source code because I happened the same and could cear the operation manually without problem.